# Adding SQLite items to a ListView

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, listview

I am working on a shopping list app and I have been stuck at adding my SQLITE data into a listview. I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) and this is my project so far.

- DbHelper class (extends SQLiteOpenHelper)
- ProductsTableModel class (creates the model for the products table)
- ListTableModel class (creates the model for list table)
- MainActvity class

The code can be found on paste bin at http://pastebin.com/u/fiverivers

I'm not sure if it's clear from my code but I have created a table called SHOPPER which is suppose to tie together the LISTS and PRODUCTS tables.

The user will be presented with a listview which will allow you to add new shopping lists, these shopping lists (which make up the rows in the listview) will open a new activity when clicked.
This new activity will also contain a listview but instead of shopping list names it will have products in the list.

So finally my question is how do I take this SQL data and put it into a ListView? I have checked loads of different tutorials but that's just confusing me the more I read them.

I know I need an Adapter (Simple cursor adapter?) and a cursor but I have no idea how to implement this in the context of my code.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ListView and SQLite, you should use a Cursor Adapter.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

Extends from SimpleCursorAdapter, override the newView and bindView method and set the adapter in ListView.

Check this tutorial:
http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/